# Can't bind to [(ngModel)] since it is not provided by any applicable directives

Tags: angular, webstorm

I just started to study Angular and wanted to try to implement 2 way binding.

***app.module.ts***

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***app.component.ts***

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sample text';
}
```

***app.component.html***

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title">
<p>{{title}}</p>
```

This code runs and works as it should, but for some reason in the IDE (I am using WebStorm) I get this error:

[image]

P.S.
Yes, I read the topics related to this error, but all the answers say just import FormsModule, and I did it anyway.

P.P.S
I noticed that IDE was working fine before running the ng serve command.

Comment: Its your IDE's issue. I don't think you need to worry about that.

Comment: I was using Intellij and upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Ultimate Edition). The issue was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue with webstorm today as well after performing an Angular version update (from 10->12). Angular 12 uses a newer Typescript version which I believe caused this error in the IDE. Updating to the latest webstorm version fixed it for me.

Comment: I had the latest version of webstorm, but reinstalling the old version of angular helped me (from 12 to 11)

Answer (score 1):

You also get this error when you are trying to do two way binding and your @Input and @Output don't match in name with "Change" at the end of the Output variable according to [this rule](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works):

> For two-way data binding to work, the @Output() property must use the pattern, inputChange, where input is the name of the @Input() property. For example, if the @Input() property is size, the @Output() property must be sizeChange.

So in my case I was getting the "Can't bind to [(person)] since it is not provided by any applicable directives" error since my input was named "person" and my output was named "personEvent" when it expects the output to be "personChange". So within your child component (in my case SelectPerson.ts), your typescript would be like this:

```
private _person: string;
@Input()
set person(val: string) {
  this.personChange.emit(val);
  this._person = val;
}
get person() {
  return this._person;
}

@Output() personChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

And within your parent component html:

```html
<app-select-person [(person)]="manager"> </app-select-person>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the forms module was missing from the module imports. Add the import to fix it.

`import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";`

and

`imports: FormsModule`

in the app.module or the module that the input is used in.